# C# Console Program issues

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, console

I need help in understanding what may be wrong with this simple C# console app program. What I want to do, is perform various arithmetic operations via classes. Here is the program.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Arithmetic a1 = new Arithmetic();
        Console.Write("\nEnter the value for first variable\n");
        a1.obj1 = Console.Read();
        Console.Write("\nEnter the value for the second variable\n");
        a1.obj2 = Console.Read();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Apparantley, the program builds and compiles ok, but on the run time it takes the value of the first integer, and without taking the value of the next integer, it writes the last line on the display (Press any key to exit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Console.Read()` reads a **single character** from standard input, and returns its ASCII value.
If you press two keys, each `Console.Read()` call will return one of them

You probably want `ReadLine()`, which reads an entire line of text (which you will then want to parse into an `int`).